# jpeg_read_header() crashed in pyd file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gcc, libjpeg, pyd

I'm programming with libjpeg and the problem came. Fortunately, I found some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092251/alternatives-to-jpeg-read-header-libjpeg) and tried feeding from jpeg_mem_src() rather than jpeg_stdio_src(), compiling **pyd** file with VS2010 or gcc, analyzing pyd with dependencywalker and adding some dlls. But these solutions all failed.

Could anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: You will need to provide more information, what are you trying to do? are you creating the image that causes the crash? what is the crash information you got? are you able to open jpeg you downloaded from the internet with your code?

Comment: I'm trying to read DCT coefficients from jpeg file. According to debugging, it always said unhandled exception caused by writing accessing violation.

Comment: That error sounds like either your code is invalid, or the image is, did you try to download some image from the Internet and see if it works with it?

Comment: Thank you! I solved it myself by using jpeglib-static.lib of libjpeg-turbo.